# Disect Log returned from compiling Python File in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, string

I have been able to compile a python program from a java program. I am capturing the errors found in the python program and getting it printed out in the console. 
I am not getting all the errors in the .py file at one go. **I have to correct the previous error and run it again to get the next error.** And below is sample of what I get in my console:
[image]

I need to capture only the line numbers and the syntax error e.g: pint.

Here's a sample of my program where log is string which holds the details about the error found:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Python_Compiler {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String ret = compile();
        System.out.println(ret);

    }
        public static String compile()
        {
            String log="";
            String myDirectory = "C:\\";
             try {
                 String s= null;
               //change this string to your compilers location
                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C python Hello.py", null, new java.io.File(myDirectory));

             BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
             boolean error=false; 

             log+="";
             while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                 log+=s;
                 error=true;
                 log+="\n";

             }if(error==false) log+="Compilation Successful !!!";


         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
             return log;
        }


      public int runProgram() 
        {
            int ret = -1;
           try
             {            
                 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                 Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start a.exe");
                 proc.waitFor();
                 ret = proc.exitValue();
             } catch (Throwable t)
               {
                 t.printStackTrace();
                 return ret;
               }
           return ret;                      
        }}
```

**Can anyone help in extracting only the line number and syntax error and have it stored in an array?**

Answer (score 0):

So you want to capture the line number which is 3 and the error which is prit.